# How to use @Value to read from application.properties then use the value to initilize instance variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I have code as follows:

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class test {
    @Value("${valueFromApplicationProperties}")
    String valueFromApplicationProperties;

    @Spy
    @Autowired
    ClassA a = new ClassA(valueFromApplicationProperties);

    @InjectMocks
    ClassB b;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println(valueFromApplicationProperties);
    }
}
```

(`ClassA` doesn't have a non-arg constructor, so I have to initialize it as above.)

When running, the `valueFromApplicationProperties` is `null` when being used in `new ClassA(valueFromApplicationProperties)`.

But it can be printed out in the `setup` method.

I am wondering how to solve it.

I saw some answers suggesting `PostConstruct`, but I think I cannot use it in my case.

Because `valueFromApplicationProperties` must be filled before the initialization of `ClassA a`, then object `a` can be injected in `ClassB b`.

Thus, I think the order must be `valueFromApplicationProperties` -> `a` -> `b`.

Could anyone help me with that?

I just need a way to make `valueFromApplicationProperties` filled before it is used in `ClassA a = new ClassA(valueFromApplicationProperties);`.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your `application.properties` file located in relation to the code? It looks like you're working on tests. Are these in a `test` directory? I'd also rename `application.properties` to `application-test.properties` to avoid any confusion between a production version and a test version of the properties

Comment: @RobEvans As I mentioned above, it can be printed out in the constructor. So I think the file location would be a problem.

Comment: If you are `@Autowiring` a Spring bean, you should not instantiate it yourself. What does `@Spy @Autowired ClassA a;` produce (no instantiation)?

Comment: @TheNytangel Without the instantiation, it cannot run due to the lack of a non-arg constructor. `@Spy` needs a non-arg constructor, but this class doesn't have one, and I cannot add one by myself.

Comment: Ah. In that case, it might be best to let the value be null, and then in your `@Before` method, use reflection to set the value once it is available. Something like `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(a, "fieldNameToSet", valueFromApplicationProperties);`

Comment: @TheNytangel Thanks for the hints! It works. I set the two fields in the `@Before` method.